# Union of two large tables failing on RDS Aurora

Tags: union, amazon-aurora

I have the following query

```
select count(*) from
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table_1
  UNION
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table_2
)  AS REPORT
```

The tables table_1 and table_2 have

- 65 columns each (1 date, 30 varchar and 33 int and 1 auto_increment primary key)
- ~2 GB data each
- ~2 Million rows each

I am migrating servers from RDS MySQL to RDS Aurora.
This query runs well on RDS MySQL instance.
But when i run it on Aurora instance which is a bigger instance than the MySQL instance - The aurora instance runs out of space which by the way has 70GB of free space. 
Eventually the query fails giving error as below which i understand is because of no free disk space

```
Incorrect key file for table '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sql_14be_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

What i am not able to understand is why is the query eating up 70+ GB of space for data that is hardly 4GB in the union.

Anybody has any suggestions as to what am i doing wrong and how to correct it?

Comment: What version of Aurora MySQL do you use ?

Comment: I am using Aurora 1.1 (mysql 5.6 compatible)

Comment: switched to Aurora 2.0 (mysql 5.7 compatible) to resolve the issue. didnt hear anything from AWS support as well.